# Invalid decorator usage. Supported decorators (api, wire, track) should be imported from "lwc"

Tags: lightning-web-components, vs-code

I started working with Lightning Web Components and was doing the [Quick Start: Lightning Web Components](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/create-a-hello-world-lightning-web-component) project, on deploying source to org, I am getting the following error in VS Code output Panel

```
SyntaxError: /home/sfdc/tools/lwc/0.34.7/helloWorld.js: LWC1100: Invalid decorator usage. Supported decorators (api, wire, track) should be imported from "lwc"
```

Below is code in helloWorld.js as mentioned in trailhead

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class HelloWorld extends LightningElement {
    @track greeting = 'World';
    changeHandler(event) {
        this.greeting = event.target.value;
    }
}
```

How do I import these decorators from 'lwc'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must add them to your import statement. You’re using @track, so you should have the following:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
```

You can read more about reactive properties, how to import them and use them [here](https://lwc.dev/guide/javascript_reactive).

You should have a look to the whole [Dev Guide](https://lwc.dev/guide/introduction) to learn more about LWC.